# Red Neuronal en Python con Keras para apuestas deportivas

Tags: python, tensorflow, redes-neuronales, inteligencia-artificial, keras

Estoy creando una red neuronal secuencial que me pronostique el resultado de carreras deportivas de caballos. En el array X tengo el código del caballo normalizado y en el array Y los resultados de la carrera.

Los códigos de los caballos los he normalizado con el código máximo del fichero de caballos y dividiendo el código de cada caballo por ese máximo. Así todos irán de 0 a 1. Cuando la red neuronal me de los resultados haré el proceso contrario.

He puesto en la capa de entrada 10 neuronas correspondientes a los 10 caballos de salida. Una carrera por cada fila del array X. En la capa de salida he puesto también 10 neuronas porque la red neuronal me debería devolver esos mismos códigos pero en otro orden.

El caso es que cuando entreno la red neuronal, no consigo que pase de un 60%. No controlo muy bien qué función de activación debo usar, si relu, sigmoide, etc. ¿Alguien me puede echar un cable?

```
# Creamos el Array que almacenará por fila, los 10 caballos de salida. Ahí almacenaremos su código normalizado.
# Es decir, cogeremos el código máximo de todos los del fichero y el código de cada caballos lo dividiremos por ese.
# Con lo cual todos irán de 0 a 1.
self.X = np.array([], "float64")

# Creamos el Array que almacenará por fila, la posición de llegada de los 10 caballos. También normalizados.
self.Y = np.array([], "float64")

# Buscamos el ultimo registro como valor máximo para normalizar.
self.maximo = 0
sql = 'SELECT * FROM caballos ORDER BY cod DESC LIMIT 1'
if self.modelo.lee_uno(sql, ''):
    i = 0
    for reg in self.modelo.db_registro:
        i = i + 1
        if i == 1:
            self.maximo = reg

# Leemos de las carreras las 10 posiciones de salida y de llegada. Las añadimos por filas con axis=0
sql = 'select * from carreras order by fecha asc'
self.modelo.lee_varios(sql)
for i in self.modelo.db_registros:
    self.X = np.append(self.X, self.carga_posicion_salida(str(i[0])), axis=0)
    self.Y = np.append(self.Y, self.carga_resultados(str(i[0])), axis=0)

# Creamos el objeto que contendrá a nuestra red neuronal, como secuencia de capas.
model = kr.Sequential()

capaEntrada = model.add(kr.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))
capaOculta1 = model.add(kr.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu'))
capaSalida = model.add(kr.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu'))

# Compilamos el modelo, definiendo la función de coste y el optimizador.
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Y entrenamos al modelo.
history = model.fit(self.X, self.Y, epochs=10, validation_split=0.2, verbose=1)
scores = model.evaluate(self.X, self.Y)
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1] * 100))
print(model.predict(self.X).round())

# Mostramos las variables para usarlas en plot y un resumen del modelo.
history_dict = history.history
print('')
print(history_dict.keys())
print('')
model.summary()

# Plot training & validation accuracy values
plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_accuracy'])
plt.title('ACIERTOS')
plt.ylabel('% Aciertos')
plt.xlabel('Epocas')
plt.legend(['Red Neuronal', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# Plot training & validation loss values
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('PERDIDAS')
plt.ylabel('% Perdida')
plt.xlabel('Epocas')
plt.legend(['Red Neuronal', 'Test'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()

# Salvar el modelo
model.save(r'C:\model.h5')

# Probamos el modelo con la carrera nº 2
self.X = np.array([], "float64")
self.Y = np.array([], "float64")

self.X = np.append(self.X, self.carga_posicion_salida(str(2)), axis=0)
print('Posiciones de Salida ', self.X)

r = model.predict(self.X).round()
print('Resultado Carrera',r)
#for reg in np.nditer(r):
#    print(reg)
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Python estás usando?

Comment: Pues la version 3.7

Comment: Vale ya lo veo... Keras is compatible with: Python 2.7-3.6. Gracias ¡

Answer (score 1):

Vale, pues de momento esto responde a mi pregunta. En el [sitio web de Keras](https://keras.io/) se indica que es compatible con Python 2.7 a 3.6:

> Keras is compatible with: Python 2.7-3.6